# Accessing Objects without read permission for specific profiles in lightning

Tags: lightning, profile

I am getting following error while loading the lightning app:
**Invalid definition for null:dummy__c: Access to entity 'dummy__c' denied.**

Where dummy is a custom object.The profile with which I am opening the app does not have read permission to dummy object. I  have performed insert/update operations on object on server side but made all the corresponding apex classes without sharing.

Also while declaring the attribute of that object type in lightning component I have made it of SObject type.

Further while sending / recieving the object from server(apex side), I have converted it into string and then passed it.

However the fields of that object are used in components , but as I converted the object's type to Sobject I don't thing accessing fields will be issue here.

Still It is giving me same error and I am unable to open the APP.Also not a single console log shows up even that of init.

Where am I  going wrong.

Comment: Are you hosting that page in community?

Comment: I think with and without sharing keyword only works with Sharing rules and not for object and field level security. [Even with "without sharing", I still have to give profile access to objects/fields. Is this correct?](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092dAIAQ)

Comment: @αΥβ Yes hosting that  page in community, but currently logging via app which is not for community.Created two different apps one for community and one for normal users

Comment: Understood. So if I want to query on particular object or perform DML operations on object then I have to give atleast the read permission to User. However , If I a m performing DML insert or upsert on Record of particular object then Without sharing will work.For Example, I passed an object to apex controller from Lighnitng component as a string and then performed insert operation on it after typecasting so It worked.